# Adding a counter column for a set of similar rows in R

Tags: r

I have a data-frame in R with two columns. The first column contains the subjectID and the second column contains the trial ID that subject has done.

The a specific subjectID might have done the trial for more than 1 time. I want to add a column with a counter that starts counting for each subject-trial unique value and increment by 1 till it reaches the last row with that occurance.

More precisely, I have this table:

```
ID T
A  1
A  1
A  2
A  2
B  1
B  1
B  1
B  1
```

and I want the following output

```
ID  T  Index
A   1   1
A   1   2
A   2   1
A   2   2
B   1   1
B   1   2
B   1   3
B   1   4
```

Comment: ...and many, many others.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. But I have been trying to up-vote your answer since yesterday. But it doesn't let me do this. I still have < 15 reputation score.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I really like the simple syntax of `data.table` for this (not to mention speed)...

```
#  Load package
require( data.table )
#  Turn data.frame into a data.table
dt <- data.table( df )

#  Get running count by ID and T
dt[ , Index := 1:.N , by = c("ID" , "T") ]
#   ID T Index
#1:  A 1     1
#2:  A 1     2
#3:  A 2     1
#4:  A 2     2
#5:  B 1     1
#6:  B 1     2
#7:  B 1     3
#8:  B 1     4
```

`.N` is an integer equal to the number of rows in each group. The groups are defined by the column names in the `by` argument, so `1:.N` gives a vector as long as the group.

As `data.table` inherits from `data.frame` any function that takes a `data.frame` as input will also take a `data.table` as input and you can easily convert back if you wished ( `df <- data.frame( dt )` )